# how to run swift server single process

Tags: swift, ubuntu, server, kitura, server-side-swift

I'm trying to run a swift based web server using Kitura on Ubuntu.
This is following command to start hello word server.
`.build/debug/helloworld`
I can launch standalone process using `.build/debug/helloworld &`
but launching with that creates multiple process if execute again. 
Or I've to kill old process then start new If I want to run only single process.

I've followed following tutorial to get server up running. But don't want to use Bluemix to deploy application. Instead I want to launch it on AWS ubuntu.
http://www.kitura.io/en/starter/gettingstarted.html

I assume there must be more easy and proper way to do this.

As you can see I'm almost newbie for servers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to kill the Kitura process in order to stop a Kitura Server app - there is no other way to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test your server you can run it inside a screen session. Screen is an essential utility for managing remote servers via ssh.

If you want to run it properly as a service/daemon you should look into systemd.